# Polymer and advanced css selectors using polyfill-next-selector

Tags: css, polymer

I've got what I'd consider an advanced use case for this which probably doesn't apply to 90% of use cases but here goes.

I have some HTML (components) markup that looks like this

```
<my-element>

  <div class="element1"></div> <!-- i am hidden -->

  <div class="element2"></div>

</my-element>
```

And my parent element is in charge of styling it's children, so I'd say that's okay because you can use the following

```
polyfill-next-selector { content: ".element1" } 
::content .element1 { display: none; }
```

Good, now I want to do something else when my parent element obtains a new class or attribute.

```
<my-element class="showElement1">

    <div class="element1"></div> <!-- show me now -->

    <div class="element2"></div>

</my-element>

// Here is the confusing part
polyfill-next-selector { content: ".element1" } 
:host(.showElement1) ::content .element1 { display: block; }
```

Works just fine in chrome, but the polyfill breaks in other browsers.

For example, I'd expect to see the following CSS markup rendered by the polyfill.

```
my-element.showElement1 .element1 { display: block; }
```

But this does not get created.

Am I simply mis-interpreting the way the :host and ::content systems work or is this a bug with the polyfiller that needs to be catered for?

Comment: Why did you edit it and why is it marked down?

Comment: This could be a bug in the style shimmer. Do you have the rule it actually creates? Have you tried `polyfill-next-selector { content: ":host.showElement1 .element1" }`?

Comment: Hi Eric, Yes I tried `polyfill-next-selector { content: ":host.showElement1 .element1" }` however same result. Firefox style editor window suggests it's not printing any styles out at all.

Comment: Take a look at `<style>` injected in the head and see what it came out with. If it's a bug, please file at https://github.com/polymer/polymer/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting confused by the `::content` and the `content: ""`. They're not related in the same way.

The trick is knowing that the content of the `content: ""` portion of the code is what gets read and converted by the polyfill into your final CSS.

```
polyfill-next-selector { content: ":host.showElement1 .element1" }
```

Becomes:

```
my-element.showElement1 .element1
```

And in browsers that don't require the polyfill (i.e. chrome 38 latest at time of writing) stays the same. i.e:

```
:host.showElement1 ::content .element1 {}
```

And finally, to make it work properly, you need to keep it all together so it reads like this

```
polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host.showElement1 .element1'; }
:host(.showElement1) ::content .element1 {
  display: block;
}
```

Posted as an answer for reference in case there are other people out there who might have been confused by the same situation I faced.